# Add role by ID : interactions.py

Tags: python, discord, discord-interactions

I want to create a bot that creates three buttons and assigns a different role to each one.

My problem is that every method i use it dosn't work. It's my first discord bot project.

```py
@slash_command(name="give_role")
async def give_role(ctx: SlashContext, role: Role):
    await ctx.author.add_roles(1210596582387490877)
    await ctx.send(f"Die Rolle {role.name} wurde dir erfolgreich gegeben.")
```

This is the code I made. But I have an error message: `TypeError: give_role() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'role'`

My seccond problem is that i don't know how to save the role.id in the buttons

Comment: Wherever you're calling the `give_role()` method, you aren't passing it the role argument, hence the type error

Comment: Thanks. But how do I pass the argument to give_role() or is there another way to solve this?

Comment: assuming that you're only wanting to add the specific role given by the id, you should be able to get the name of that role using the `interactions.py` API and the `id` you've specified